# Xamarin forms can't get Menupage to display color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When my app loads the TitleView BackgroundColor starts after the menu.png icon. I can only get it to work after I select one of the menu items where I set the  detailPage.BarBackgroundColor?

> Is there anyway to set this color in the mainpage.xml or the menupage.xaml?

[image: Add Color to the menu.png]

Mainpage.xaml

```
    <pages:MenuPage x:Name="menuPage"/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage BackgroundColor="#22335c">
        <x:Arguments>
            <pages:HomePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs
This will only set the color

```
var detailPage = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
detailPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#22335c");
```

MenuPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Pages.MenuPage"
             xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives"
             xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
             xmlns:model="clr-Model"
             xmlns:page="clr-Pages"
             Title="Menu"  Icon="menu.png" BackgroundColor="#22335c" >
    <Grid>
```

homepage.xaml

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#22335c" >
        <Label Text="App" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#22335c" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Comment: I didn't understand ...

Are you painting NavigationPage with background color #22335c, and the title view with the same #22335c ...

Did you insert a icon for this hamburger menu ? Can you use a icon ?

Comment: @GuilhermeMarques I am using a icon menu.png fon the menupage.xaml. I have the NavigationPage.TitleView control with looks like it is overlapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First at all, if you want a white background, try to use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Pages.MenuPage"
             xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives"
             xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
             xmlns:model="clr-Model"
             xmlns:page="clr-Pages"
             Title="Menu"  Icon="menu.png" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" >
```

or use it :

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" >
        <Label Text="App" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#22335c" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  />
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

I prefer use it :

```
  MainPage = new NavigationPage (new MainView()) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.White, BarTextColor = Color.NavyBlue };
```

If you want to overlap 2 tipes of blue, try to use a icon without background. Make or take a SVG figure for example and convert in png using paint.

This figure is a sample for you:
[Figure without background link](https://unixtitan.net/images/1-vector-transparent-background.png)

[image: Figure Sample]

Regards

Comment: i have tried both your suggestion and it still will not display the color I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am somewhat puzzled as it seems to be too obvious, but this works:

```
    <pages:MenuPage x:Name="menuPage"/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor ="#22335c">
        <x:Arguments>
            <pages:HomePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```